# Inject mock object without java interface for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking

My java project has multiple layers such as Controller (depends on) Service (depends on) DAO. 
My goal is to unit test Controller.

I created Mock service object to inject it in to Controller class.

After googling , Ive learnt that I could use java interface to do so.

Ideally, service layer does not need an interface.

I wonder if there is a different approach to inject mock object without a java interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are mocking libraries like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/), which could create mocks for classes without the need of interfaces.

```
MyService serviceMock = org.Mockito.mock(MyService.class);
controller.setService(serviceMock);
```

Comment: Thanks @StefanBirkner. Problem solved. FYI : you need to pass   MyService.class in mock(..) . BTWN Ive used @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) to initialze mock objects.. code is much cleaner.

Comment: With it's clean api and features like this it baffles me that Mockito isn't the de facto standard for mocking in java.

Answer (score 1):

If a class in controller uses a service class, you can mock the service class an inject into the controller class when you are unit testing the controller class.

```
public class MyController {
    private MyService myService;

    public void setMyService(MyService myService) {
        this.myservice = myservice;
    }
}
```

Whether you mock an interface or a class depends on the reference type that the controller class has.

In above example, if `MyService` is an interface you can mock that interface. But if it is a class, then you have to mock that class.

Hope that resolves your concern.